# How to Insert to multi MYSQL tables C# fast?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am trying to insert some data into two MYSQL tables.
the second table stores the first table row Id as a foreign key. 
I have this code that works fine but it is super slow. what is the best/fastest way to make it faster?

```
string ConnectionString = "server=localhost; password = 1234; database = DB ; user = Jack";
        MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        mConnection.Open();
        int index = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {

            string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO myentities(Name) VALUES (@first_name);"
                    + "INSERT INTO secondtable(Id, Name,myentities) VALUES (@ID, @city, LAST_INSERT_ID());";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, mConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", "Jack");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", i+1);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "Frank");

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
```

I have found the following code on one of the StackoverFlow questions but it was inserting data to a single table only, not to multiple tables which are connected through a foreign key.
This code is pretty fast, but I was not sure how I can make it work with multiple tables.

```
    public static void BulkToMySQL()
{
    string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1xxx";
    StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ");           
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test"), MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test")));
        }
        sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
        sCommand.Append(";");
        mConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), mConnection))
        {
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you found is also painfully insecure. It's practically begging to get hacked. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way possible is to craft a strategy for not calling mysql in a loop via the .NET MySQL Connector. Especially for i=0 to 99999 . The way you achieve this is either thru ***CASE A:*** direct db table manipulation or ***CASE B:*** thru CSV to db imports with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

For ***CASE B:*** it is often wise to bring that data into a *staging table* or tables. Checks can be made for data readiness depending on the particular circumstances. What that means is that you may be getting external data that needs scrubbed ([ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)). Other benefits include not committing unholy data to your production tables not fit for consumption. So it leaves an abort option open to you.

Now onto performance anecdotes. With MySQL and the .NET Connector version 6.9.9.0 in late 2016, I can achieve up to 40x performance gains by going this route. It may seem unnatural not to call an `INSERT` query but I don't in loops. Ok, sure, in small loops, but not in data ingest with bulk. Not even for 500 rows. You will experience noticable UX improvement if you re-craft some routines.

So the above is for data that truly came from external sources. For ***CASE A:*** the normal data that is already in your db the above does not apply. In those situations you strive to craft your SQL to massage your data as much as possible (read: 100%) on the server-side. As such it does so without bringing the data back to the client thus requiring some client-side with Connector looping call to get it back into the server. This does not mandate Stored Procedures necessarily or at all. Client-side calls that operate on the data in place without toward client transfers then back up are what you shoot for.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain some improvement by moving unnecessary operations out of the loop, since anything you do there is repeated 100,000 times:

```
string insertPerson = 
     "INSERT INTO myentities(Name) VALUES (@first_name);"
   + "INSERT INTO secondtable(Id, Name,myentities) VALUES (@ID, @city, LAST_INSERT_ID());";
string ConnectionString = "server=localhost; password = 1234; database = DB ; user = Jack";

using (var Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, mConnection))
{
    //guessing at column types and lengths here 
    command.Parameters.Add("@first_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Jack";
    var id = command.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    command.Parameters.Add("@city", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Frank";


    mConnection.Open();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
    {
        id.Value = i;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But mostly, you try to *avoid this scenario.* Instead, you'd do something like use a numbers table to project the results for both tables in advance. There are [some things you can do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) with foreign key constraints to set locking (you need to lock the whole table to avoid bad keys if someone else inserts or tries to read partially inserted records), transaction logging (you can set it only log the batch, rather than each change) and foreign keys enforcment (you can turn it off while you handle the insert).